# How can I create a new Google Doc in the same folder entitled with the text of the current sentence where the cursor is located?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

### My goal

Let's say I am editing Google Doc #1.

Now let's say I decide, "Hey, I would like to create a new Google Doc entitled, 'I like cheese pizza' in the same folder as Google Doc #1."

Furthermore, let's say I would like the Google Doc named, "I like cheese pizza" to contain a first paragraph which consists of the text, "I like cheese pizza".

### How would I accomplish my goal?

I am imagining that while I am editing Google Doc #1,  I would type, "I like cheese pizza" and then run an Apps Script.

### Possibly helpful examples

As an example, among other things, the following script, which I found at [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs), inserts a paragraph that contains the same text as the document's name...

```
function createDoc() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Plants', 'Animals'], ['Ficus', 'Goat'], ['Basil', 'Cat'], ['Moss', 'Frog']];
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

[How can I retrieve the sentence where the cursor currently resides in a Google Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752655/how-can-i-retrieve-the-sentence-where-the-cursor-currently-resides-in-a-google-d) apparently accomplishes what it says.

```
var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
var surroundings = cursor.getSurroundingText();
var marker = '\u200B';  // A zero-wdith space character - i.e. a hidden marker.
cursor.insertText(marker);
var surroundingTextStr = surroundings.getText();  // Copy to string
surroundings.replaceText(marker, '');  // Remove the marker from the document.

// Build sentence pattern, allowing for marker.
var pattern = /([A-Z\u200B][^\.!?]*[\.!?])/ig;  
var match;
while ((match = pattern.exec(surroundingTextStr)[0]) != null){
  Logger.log(match);
  if (/\u200B/.test(match)){
    match = match.replace(marker, '');
    Logger.log("We found the sentence containing the cursor!");
    Logger.log(match);
  }
}
```

Of course the following would create a text file named "'New Text File" with the text, "Hello, world!" That's not what I want. Yet I suppose it still might be helpful. [Creates a text file in the current folder with the given name and contents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content)...

```
// Create a text file with the content "Hello, world!"
DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile('New Text File', 'Hello, world!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do. It creates a menu from where you can invoke the script. I don't know about the use case but maybe managing new files with sheets is simpler?

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('NewDoc')
    .addItem('Create', 'newDocWithSentense')
    .addToUi();
}

function newDocWithSentense() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const cursor = doc.getCursor();
  const surroundings = cursor.getSurroundingText().getText();

  const currentFileFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getParents().next()
  const newDoc = DocumentApp.create(surroundings).getId()
  DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc).moveTo(currentFileFolder)
}
```

Comment: The use case is as follows: I tend to use Google Docs as if it were a wiki (kind of like Wikipedia). For example, I frequently link a word or phrase in Google Doc #1 to Google Doc #2. Imagine I were writing about fruit. Google Doc #1 might be about bananas, Google Doc #2 might be about oranges, and Google Doc Google Doc #3 might be about apricots. Just like Wikipedia, I typically link those documents to one another.

Comment: Now let's suppose I was just beginning to write about fruits in Google Doc #1 named "Bananas", yet Google Doc #2 and Google Doc #3 were not yet extant (did not yet exist). While typing in Google Doc #1—"Bananas"—I might type, "Bananas are easier to peel than oranges." Then I might then highlight the word "oranges", press copy, create a new Google Doc (let's call it Google Doc #2) and title that document "Oranges." Then I would link Google Doc #1 ("Bananas") to Google Doc #2 ("Oranges").

Comment: Maybe [notion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2G-uVDB28A&ab_channel=Notion) is a way better fit..?

Comment: I have carefully considered Notion, as well Obsidian, Jira and a couple of dozen other options. Many are extremely popular and very powerful, yet none seem like they would be a good fit for me. For example, let's look at Notion's claims about GDPR  https://www.notion.so/help/gdpr-at-notion as well as this on Hacker News https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27148465. With Google Docs and Google Sheets plus some Google Apps Scripts I can not only backup my "Google wiki" but, if necessary, I could recreate that wiki, with all of its links **intact**, for example, on a VPS at Hetzner.

Comment: Google Docs and Google Sheets plus some Google Apps Scripts can be vastly more powerful than any other solution I found in my research. Furthermore, based on my research and experience, Google Docs and Google Sheets are also extremely reliable. The couple of dozen "wiki features" I would like for my "Google Wiki" are almost trivial compared to many of the remarkably complex Google Apps Scripts used in myriad critical business applications for small, medium and, even large businesses.

Comment: Editing documents in Notion is superb compared to, for example, Trello or Wikipedia. But from my vantage point, editing documents in Notion is vastly inferior to Google Docs and Google Sheets. All the cool kids use Notion these days. "Notion can import Excel documents!" they exclaim with admiration and excitement. Google Sheets is a spreadsheet. There's nothing to import. That's a huge difference. For my purposes a "Google wiki" seems like the best solution available. By the way, I did look at https://youneedawiki.com/. I am uninterested in it.

Comment: Lest you think I'm some sort of "mad scientist" with a harebrained scheme to use Google Docs and Google Sheets in some bizarre manner, I am not a leader: I am a follower. See https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23134101 and https://www.neat.wiki/, and https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/. Of course, merely because something is popular, doesn't mean it's good. Conversely, merely because something is unpopular, doesn't mean it's bad. Tools are like other products: they often become fads. I would gladly use Notion, if it were the best tool for my needs. But I don't think it is.

Comment: Finally, thank you very much! The code you conveyed to me did most of what I wanted OOTB (out of the box). However, lt didn't do this part... Furthermore, let's say I would like the Google Doc named, "I like cheese pizza" to contain a first paragraph which consists of the text, "I like cheese pizza".... But that's not a big deal.

Comment: Sorry for the verbosity but here's another opinion, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30371723
 ... FWIW: A previous job used confluence, but my current job just uses some shared folders in Google Drive....The search functionality is significantly better than Confluence. You just gotta accept that Google Drive doesn't look as "organized" as Confluence. The big thing, though, is you need to encourage a culture of note-taking. Take notes in tickets. Write documents in Google Drive (or whatever wiki you use.) Make sure that your ticketing and wiki system have good search.